# Python Scipy: Force Least Squares to use Positive Integer Values when minimizing

Tags: python, scipy, least-squares

I'm able to create an minimal solution for a weight multiplication problem below using the `scipy.optimize.lsq_linear`.

```
Actual = [x,y,z] * [i,j,k]
Difference = Expected - Actual
Difference is sent to the Least Squares Minimizer
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.lsq_linear.html

How do I force the target vector (output), to only use positive integers, say between 0 and 100?

I understand that I will get a non-optimal solution.

Comment: This needs so much more detail. Show the code for your invocation of `lsq_linear`. Show values for all of your parameters. Are `ijk` known beforehand, and optimal values for `xyz` are being chosen?

Comment: What is the value of the expected scalar?

Comment: Is that multiplication an element-wise multiplication, or a dot product?

Comment: Do you want to use cvxpy instead?